# Knowing usage of mapper and reducer

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, mapper, reducers

I am running a pig latin script over 550 Gb of data.
The reducer is default 1. It takes about 38 mins to generate the result.
I wanted to know if increasing the number of reducers would execute the script faster

Any help will be appreciated.

Also, I had like to know the concept behind setting mapper and reducers.

Comment: if you need more detailed explanation do let me know

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the number of reducers would certainly helps(if the operation you are performing has aggregation). As the actual aggregations happens at the reduce side,running multiple reducers would increase the performance.

You can set the number of reducers in pig using 'Parallel' key word.
ex: 
A = LOAD 'myfile' AS (t, u, v);
B = GROUP A BY t PARALLEL 18;

The number of mappers is decided by the size of the input and the input format we use.The number of mappers typically equals to the number of input splits.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers are not necessarily correct for your situation. It is true that if you have a variety of reduce keys and your dataset is not heavily skewed toward one of them, and the shuffle and/or reduce phases are the bottleneck in your operation, and you have multiple cores available to use as reducers, then adding more reducers will help. In Pig, you can specify the number you want to use with the `PARALLEL` clause.

As hinted, there are cases in which adding more reducers will not help you:

1. **You have one reduce key for the majority of your data.** If most of your data results in the same reduce key, all of the map output for that key will go to a single reducer. If you add more reducers, you will find that the others complete very quickly, but that reducer still takes a very long time to finish. If this is occurring during a Pig `JOIN`, you can get around this issue with the `USING 'skewed'` clause.
2. **The primary bottleneck is reading the data during the map phase and doing processing on it.** You say you have 550 GB of data. How many mappers are you using? How long do they take to complete? Adding more reducers can only speed up the shuffle and reduce phases.
3. **You are working on a small cluster with very few cores available for reduce tasks.** If you have set up a local Hadoop cluster on your computer, chances are you don't have more than 1 or 2 cores devoted to reduce tasks. Consequently, starting more reducers will just mean that those extra reducers have to wait their turn for CPU time and you won't be moving any faster.

Apart from adding reducers, another way to make your jobs run faster is to cut down on any unnecessary map output. All map output is written to disk, then distributed to the reducers, where it is again written to disk. Disk I/O is very slow, and if much of your data is not needed, throw it away during the map phase. In Pig, for example, you may just wish to get a count of the number of records for each key. In this case, all data except for the key should be thrown away.

---

In general, the number of mappers is chosen automatically. There are tricks you can use if you feel that the number of mappers is too small. For example, you may find that Pig is too aggressive in combining input files together, such that you only have one or two mappers that take a long time. In that case you can `SET pig.maxCombinedSplitSize` to a larger number. But usually, the number of mappers is out of your control.

The number of reducers you want to use is dependent on the resources you have available to you (i.e., How many reducers is it possible to use at once? Is it ok if your job occupies all reducers in the cluster for a long time? ) and the nature of your data (i.e., Is it heavily skewed toward one reduce key?).  Note also that you will have one output file for each reducer, so more reducers can be problematic in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , Of course you can have more than one reducer .

[image]

Different colors represent different keys. All values with the same key are presented to a single reduce task.

Which means ., You can have multiple reducer for different keys

Refer this link

https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Parallel feature available in PIG. Please refer this link for more information.[PIG Parallel Feature](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/cookbook.html#Use+the+Parallel+Features)